# Couldn't list out my array in options for my select button in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i couldn't get to display my data from firebase in select react button, it kept coming up mixed together.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "categories")
    try {
    const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
    const fecthedData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        value: doc.id,
        label: doc.data().Gyms,
    }));
    setData(fecthedData);
}catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fecthing data: ', error);
}
}
fetchData();
}, [])
```

[image: this is what i have now, i need each gym name to be an option]

Comment: Have you logged your `fetchedData`?

Comment: yeah, i did.
the data was gotten, i just couldn't get the it listed properly.

Comment: Please share your `fetchedData` and `select` component which is passing `fetchedData` as props.

Comment: I mean fetchedData, no fetchData. please log it.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: please insert `console.log(fetchedData)` above `setData(fetchedData)` and then see console.